# What is the value of maintaining an interest in catastrophe?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind

If i can't help the people I see suffering in the news, what is the value in watching it, given how bad it makes me feel?

Comment: You might expand this question by describing any conclusions you've arrived at. Why do _you_ think you watch horrendous news? What value do you think there is in maintaining an awareness of troubling global affairs? What do philosophers say in relation to the need for morality to be _informed_ morality?

Comment: You need to frame a question which can be answered by reference to recognised philosophy, as opposed to mere opinion of philosophical enthusiasts.

Comment: If you can't put the news in perspective, turn off the news. Remember, trillions of individual things happen worldwide every day. The news shows you the ones that will generate outrage and clicks.

Comment: Futilitarian, is't free expresion free?, as u altered my post , i understand free expresiion is DEAD. here at stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Cris. There are constraints upon questions, answers and comments in Stack Exchange sites which exist in the hope of maintaining a certain quality and type of exchange. It will be very useful for you to look at the [Tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour), which describes expectations here. Try not to take downvotes and close votes personally. Some of the most interesting questions are sometimes closed because they do not meet this stack's guidelines. All the best.

Comment: thank you, for the kind amability of your explanation. i understand.

Answer (score 2):

Watching the news regarding various catastrophes, as such and by itself, has no particular value. The anxiety it may produce is quite likely to have negative effects. So, without further actions, I would suggest to avoid watching the news.

My profession involves safety analysis of large engineering systems. I seek news of various catastrophes for professional reasons. Though I tend to restrict to engineering issues. There was a cable car failure a year or two ago. There have been various things such as bridge failures, apartment buildings collapsing, fires in factories, and such. I study these to find out the causes. I do that in order to attempt to learn if there are principles of safety that I may have been unaware of. Or may have been paying inadequate attention. Or just to have things to hold up in front of my coworkers (also engaged in safety analysis) and say: Here is an example of people who ignored a safety rule. Don't ignore this safety rule or this is what happens. You live next to the facility you are tasked with keeping safe. The consequences will affect you and your family if you fail.

In a wider context, there are "diffuse" things that we can do in this direction. There is no guarantee that any given action can produce results. We are dealing with large numbers of people with, at times, conflicting desires and goals. And people who, at times, behave in ways that would reasonably be called irrational. This can happen because they have faulty information. Or because they have a tragic circumstance that requires them to do short term things to survive.

But consider such things as famine in some locations. Especially sub-Saharan Africa. For decades there was famine. People would see the starving children on TV and then donate huge amounts of money for famine relief. The relief supplies would do some good.  But local warlords would confiscate large amounts of the aid material and money. They would use it to support their efforts to stay in power. They would use it to pay their henchmen. They would use it to bribe various officials. They would trade with neighbor warlords to cement their position. And when the famine started to die down, they'd herd people that were not cooperating into scrub areas of their country, producing more famine, and getting more aid. They would use famine as a terror weapon to suppress their opposition.

So, sending donations to *some* famine torn locations actually makes it *worse*.

So the conclusion is, *just* watching the news can produce bad actions. It is necessary to find the context of situations like famines, wars, etc. If you allow yourself to follow your emotions then the results will be net good only by chance. If you are going to pay attention to catastrophes then you need to pay attention to the context, background, and details. You need to get the best possible information as to the reason the situation exists so that you can guide your actions to a result that is actually better, as opposed to simply making yourself feel good. If you, for example, donate a lot of money that winds up supporting a deliberate-famine-creating warlord, you will wind up being less happy than if you simply ignored the whole things.

Once you know the context and reason, you may be able to advocate political action to correct things. Or not. There is no promise that a solution even exists. And if it does it may not be politically possible. The world is not always what we want it to be, though sometimes we can make it better. Or if it is some temporary crisis type thing like a famine or an earthquake or some such, you may be able to donate money or get your friends and neighbors to donate money.

To summarize, I suggest you choose one of the following: Ignore the news of such incidents. Or, get as detailed and accurate and complete information as you can to be able to choose actions that actually produce improvement, and be prepared to change your mind if later information tells you that you were mistaken.

Comment: well i stoped watching news since 8 years ago, at least TV news. thx for coment.  im no God to help people in trouble. i will do my best where i am, in helping others,.. in within my limits

Answer (score 2):

Many do not have such an interest. [42% of Americans actively avoid the news at least some of the time](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/jul/16/americans-avoid-news-reuters-survey). The quip goes 'no news is good news', and the legend says 'May you live in interesting times' was a curse in China.

Consider though, that both Republican candidates want to withdraw military support from Ukraine. If you didn't follow [what Russia did in Bucha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucha_massacre), perhaps stance on Ukraine wouldn't affect your vote.

In the UK the Tory Party [downgraded our national commitment to foreign aid](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/sn03714/), nominally because of the pandemic, but don't intend any return to it for at least half a decade. If you didn't follow the earthquake in Turkey and Syria, with at least 58,000 dead and far more without shelter in below freezing temperatures, then the aid budget might not matter to you - and you might fail to connect the 'small boats' of refugees trying to cross the channel to it.

News can be relentlessly and even unjustifiably negative, with especially in the USA [fear of crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_crime) increasing, even while the trend for almost all crimes has been downward since the 1980s. It's good I think to follow technology news, where the pattern is reversed, with mainly positive stories about breakthroughs and solutions, with only a few negative stories about new or more fully understood problems.

What we need, is insight into the actual character of our world, and our times. This is essential to being an informed voter, and to what issues politucians feel compelled to address. Without a free media and an informed electorate, democracy cannot succeed.

Peter Singer in 'The Life You Can Save' and 'Famine, Affluence, and Morality' uses our moral intuitions applied to the modern world, to identify the duties we have to save lives of distant people, over frivolous luxuries for ourself. A major way people avoid the recognition of this, is not to provide any coherent argument against such points, but simply to ignore what is going on in the world. That is a moral failure, and an excuse for tolerance of unnecessary suffering. By recognising, and telling others about the true situation of other people around the world, we can recognise and be motivated to act on our moral duties, rather than live in bad faith, and act in ways likely to lead to regret.

For instance, it was easy for people to ignore the horrors of slavery in the 17-1800s, and just enjoy the cheap cotton and sugar. For the UK, it was the horrific butchery involved in ending the slave revolt in Jamaica that meant the true situation could no longer be hidden, or ignored. In modern times, the Bhopal Diaster and the [Rana Plaza garment factory collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Rana_Plaza_factory_collapse), have revealed lack of safety and accoubtability around our modern goods, a lot like the mine collapses that led to the beginning of UK health and safety law and workplace rights (a match factory was also key). The Hillsborough Football Stadium Disaster and Grenfell Tower Disaster were horrific, tragic. And led to a huge shifts in UK law, on sports stadiums, and high-rise building safety. It's crucial that the actions match the tragedy, in order to stop them never happening again. That means fully absorbing them, being fully aware how bad they were, unflinchingly.

Comment: Downvoted for war propaganda where none was needed. And on the day after the 20th anniversary of the US invasion of Iraq. Didn't you bloodthirsty warmongers learn anything?

Comment: @user4894: Are you taking issue with the evidence? https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/icc-investigation-bucha-war-crimes-b2057997.html War crimes by Russian soldiers have been extraordinarily well documented, including often on CCTV https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/article/russian-soldiers-cleansing-operation-bucha-ukraine I expect you have some bizarre excuse for ignoring evidence presented to your own eyes.

Comment: The Bucha incident was roundly and soundly debunked at the time. And as I say, your war propaganda has nothing to do with the topic at hand. There was a peace proposal on the table in March, 2022, which the US squelched. The war is run for the benefit of the defense contractors and the national security state that Truman, Ike, and JFK warned us about. I for one and many others have had enough of the warmongering.

Comment: Debunked huh. Is that why the International Criminal Court stopped pursuing it. No wait.. The alleged peace accord was irrelevant, because no Ukrainian leader could have stayed in power presenting it. Ukraine beat Russia away from Kyev without additional weapons, & the idea the USA or anyone else could have made Ukraine's decisions for it is ludicrous. I say again, how do you deal with the explicit video footage of Russian soldiers committing war crimes.

Comment: Ahhhh, the ICC. To which the US is not a signatory. Why is that? It's because if we were, they'd indict a few US presidents. This is not the place to litigate the war in Ukraine, which is a very complex and awful situation. But neither is this the place to spout mainstream war propaganda. You said your piece and you got pushed back on. Go learn something about the history of Ukraine, the 2014 CIA-backed coup, and the Nazis you support. https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/ukraine-has-nazi-problem-vladimir-putin-s-denazification-claim-war-ncna1290946

Comment: @user4894: Ignoring one of the most well-documented war crimes in history isn't 'pushing back', it's putting your fingers in your ears & going 'la la la' because you find the real world too scary to address. Putin has been assassinating people around the world. His policies of targetting civilian infrastructure & kidnapping children are formally war crimes, happening in full view. If the presence of Nazis justifies an invasion, the USA better watch out, the far right is much bigger there.

Comment: There are horrendous war crimes on both sides. In terms of kidnapping, Ukranian recruiters are forcibly taking people off the street and making them fight.  You can look up "Ukraine forced conscription" and learn about it. What you are doing is called an appeal to emotion. You take the war crimes of one side, reported of course by the media of the other side, and think that constitutes a logical argument that one side's good and the other bad. And as I noted, the US isn't a signatory to the war crimes court, because Bush, Clinton, Obama, and Trump know we'd be the next to be indicted.

Comment: CriglCragl , welli understand your point, im from Romania, i personaly have a russian friend, dow i hate what russia is doing, i think that kremlin and its comunists have to understand that the free world wont allow bulies,  //// allso what US has done in the past attacking countries , one after a other, isnt a good record, and most west european countries had the blood of countles african people on theyr hand, from the colonization age...so noone is a angel. Wwhat is important is that Romania, Poland Will contiue suport for Ukraine. Still smell the ugly presence of russian comunism.